# How to change location of HTML element in the table

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have this HTML code:

```
    <table style="cursor: pointer; width: 100%">
        <asp:Repeater ID="PervousResultsList" runat="server" EnableViewState="False">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="3">
                        <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl="~/Images/pushpinred.png" runat="server" Width="32" Height="32" />
                    </td>
                    <tr>
                        <td>X:</td>
                        <td>
                            <%# Eval("Lon") %>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Y:</td>
                        <td>
                            <%# Eval("Lat") %>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" id="ddd" value="B" style="height: 30px;" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </table>
```

Here how it looks in view:

[image]

I need to change the view, and I want it will look like that:

[image]

I need to pick up the element Button on the line above and move to the left as you see it on the screen shot above.

Comment: Your b should have a rowspan, no?

Comment: @malix, I tryed this:      
<td rowspan="5"> <input type="button" id="ddd" value="B" style="height: 30px;" /> </td>

But I didn't get desired result.

Comment: Should work... Create a jsfiddle?Maybe just try with div's flexboxed or floating or  position:absolute?

Comment: Can you post the rendered HTML

Comment: This old question seems to need more information, but that has not been provided, so I wonder if it should be closed as 'too broad'?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
<tr>
    <td rowspan="2">
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl="~/Images/pushpinred.png" runat="server" Width="32" Height="32" />
    </td>
    <td>X:</td>
    <td>
        <%# Eval("Lon") %>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="2">
        <input type="button" id="ddd" value="B" style="height: 30px;" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Y:</td>
    <td>
        <%# Eval("Lat") %>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And if you want an empty row between items, you can define a SeparatorTemplate with:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: tnx for the answer what if I press B button need to hide dislpayed data and to show this row: <tr class="pointDescArea">
                            <td>Text:</td>
                            <td rowspan="2">
                                <h1 style="color: gray"><%# Eval("Text") %></h1>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
If I press another second time on B button  Text  hided and X and Y  displayed again. Do you have idea how to implement it?

Comment: What is that other row supposed to look like? Can you show an example of it in your question?

Comment: Yeas I will post later